# Display XML in CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xquery

My XML structure looks a bit like this:

```
<Bookmark>
    <Type>Media</Type>
    <Name>YouTube</Name>
    <Link>https://www.youtube.com</Link>
</Bookmark>
<Bookmark>
    ...
</Bookmark>
...
```

What I want to do is to display in html a table where the bookmark `Name` is displayed in a column according to the `Type` of bookmark that it is (i.e. a column for media bookmarks, a column for work bookmarks etc) and that name is a link to the address provided by `Link`.

This is what I have so far (modified from w3schools):

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/bookmarks.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Bookmark");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{ 
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "Social")
    {
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name"[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    } 
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

This displays all the social bookmarks as I wanted. The part I am struggling with is making the results a link and applying my CSS to them.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way totally, any advice would be appreiciated (note: my next to do item is to allow a web based interface to add and delete bookmarks - is this possible using the same techniques as below or do I need to go into XQuery or something similar?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a column per bookmark type, I'll suggest you to store each bookmark set (media, etc.) in an array, and then generate your table by browsing your arrays (i.e. for each `<tr[i]/>` write `<td>media[i]</td>` , `<td>work[i]</td>`, etc.). Of course be carreful with the size of your arrays (no more bookmarks = empty cells).

To write a link, you can write this :

```
document.write("<a href=\"" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("Link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "\">";
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</a>");
```

There are several ways to apply a css to this table. If you want to apply it only to *this* table, you can write :

```
document.write("<table id=\"bookmarks\">");
```

Then in your CSS (for example):

```
#bookmarks {/* stuff */}
#bookmarks tr {/* trs stuff */}
#bookmarks td {/* tds stuff */}
/* whaterver */
```

Maybe I didn't catch your real question. Can you tell more about your issue ?

Another point : I don't understand why you're using `document.write()`... Have you heard about HTML DOM reference to edit dynamically HTML content ?

Comment: As you say, `document.write()` is bad. Better rewrite that part.

Comment: Also making asynchronous request calls (i.e. `xmlhttp.open(method,url,**true**);`) will allow you a more friendly interface - dynamically page updating without freezing it.

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to use XSLT. This will transform the XML into HTML. Use CSS to style this HTML.

See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp for the code.